# Using average value to find average with respect to t and s.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Having trouble setting up and evaluating the following problem:

If a freely falling body starts from rest, then its displacement is given by `s=1/2gt^2`. Let the velocity after a time T be `v_T`. Show that if we compute the average of the velocities with respect to `t` we get `v_ave = 1/2v_T`, but if we compute the average velocities with respect to `s` we get `v_ave = 2/3v_T`

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

So we have $s(t) = \frac{1}{2}gt^2$ therefore $v(t) = gt$.  So compute the average velocity with respect to time, then we integrate the velocity over time and divide by the total time:

$$
v_{avg_t} = \frac{\int\limits_0^T gtdt}{T - 0} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}gT^2}{T} = \frac{1}{2}gT = \frac{1}{2}v_T
$$

because $v(T) = gT = v_T$.  BTW, this is the usual definition of "average velocity": $v_{avg} = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$.

If, however, we want to find the *spacial* average, that is the average velocity over the displacement, then we need to do a different integral:

$$
v_{avg_s} = \frac{\int\limits_{s_0}^{s_T}v(t)ds}{s_T - s_0}
$$

Notice that we have a mix of variables: $t$ and $s$.  We can use substitution to find $ds$ in terms of $dt$:

$$
\frac{ds}{dt} = v(t) \rightarrow ds = v(t)dt
$$

Therefore we have:

$$
v_{avg_s} = \frac{\int\limits_{0}^{T}v^2(t)dt}{s_T - s_0} = \frac{\int\limits_{0}^{T}g^2t^2dt}{s_T - s_0} = \frac{\frac{g^2T^3}{3}}{\frac{1}{2}gT^2} = \frac{2}{3}gT = \frac{2}{3}v_T
$$

Notice that in the substitution the limits of integration "magically" changed from $s_0$ to $s_T$ to $t = 0$ to $t = T$.  This is because, since we changed the integration to be over $t$ we need to find the $t$ values where $s = s_0$ and $s = s_T$--by definition these must occur at $t = 0$ and $t = T$, respectively.

Alternatively, you could find $v$ in terms of $s$:

\begin{align}
s(t) = \frac{1}{2}gt^2 \rightarrow&\ t = \sqrt{\frac{2s}{g}}\\
v(t) = gt \rightarrow&\ v(s) = g\sqrt{\frac{2s}{g}} = \sqrt{2gs}
\end{align}

Now the integral becomes

$$
\require{cancel}
\sqrt{2g}\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}gT^2} \sqrt{s}ds = \sqrt{2g}\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}gT^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{1}{3}g^{\frac{1}{2}}g^{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\cancel{2^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 2}}{\cancel{2^{\frac{3}{2}}}}T^3 = \frac{g^2T^3}{3}
$$

which is the same result we got from the substitution above.

Comment: How would you get the answer on the last line to equal 2/3vt

Comment: By dividing by the interval $s_T - s_0 = \frac{1}{2}gT^2$ just as in the one using substitution.